# Final arguments in interface methods - what's the point?

Tags: java, class, interface, methods, final

In Java, it is perfectly legal to define `final` arguments in interface methods and do not obey that in the implementing class, e.g.:

```
public interface Foo {
    public void foo(int bar, final int baz);
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo {

    @Override
    public void foo(final int bar, int baz) {
        ...
    }
}
```

In the above example, `bar` and `baz` has the opposite `final` definitions in the class VS the interface.

In the same fashion, no `final` restrictions are enforced when one class method extends another, either `abstract` or not.

While `final` has some practical value inside the class method body, is there any point specifying `final` for interface method parameters?

Comment: `final` doesn't do anything with native types anyway, since they're copied.

Comment: Just as a point of discussion: I just tried it and if two `interface` definitions vary only in the `final` attribute of an argument, then the resulting `.class` files are byte-for-byte identically (and of course `javap -v` produces the same output). The same is true for two classes that only differ in `final` on an attribute, by the way!

Comment: @Paul: it does exactly the same thing as with reference types: it prevents the arguments itself to be modified (if used in the implementation).

Comment: It has as much relevance as the public in the method signature.

Comment: could anyone post a working example on this issue.?

Comment: @Deepak - what's wrong with OP's code as an example? It seems perfectly clear.

Comment: @Deepak: I see you asking for working examples on all kinds of questions, even when it doesn't seem to make a lot of sense. I think you should try learning some abstract thinking: try thinking about a problem **without** having some executable code in front of you. It will help you a lot in the long run.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

It doesn't seem like there's any point to it. According to the [Java Language Specification 4.12.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4):

> Declaring a variable final can serve
>   as useful documentation that its value
>   will not change and can help avoid
>   programming errors.

However, a `final` modifier on a method parameter is not mentioned in the [rules for matching signatures](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#38649) of overridden methods, and it has no effect on the caller, only within the body of an implementation. Also, as noted by Robin in a comment, the `final` modifier on a method parameter has no effect on the generated byte code. (This is not true for other uses of `final`.)

Comment: Does method parameter also qualify as a variable? It obviously is in practice, but is it in specification context?

Comment: It can't be used to match signatures since it is does not appear in the actual .class file.  It is for the compiler only.

Comment: @mindas - the JLS says that there are [seven kinds of variables](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/typesValues.html#4.12.3). Method paramaters are fourth on the list.

Comment: Documentation is next to useless, however, since the `final` modifier is not enforced on the implementing class. Your interface signature may simply lie.

Comment: The Java 8 language spec now says that there are [eight kinds of variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.3) (up from seven--they added _lambda parameters_). Method parameters are still fourth on the list (at least some things in life seem stable. :-)).

Answer (score 28):

Some IDEs will copy the signature of the abstract/interface method when inserting an implementing method in a sub class.

I don't believe it makes any difference to the compiler.

EDIT: While I believe this was true in the past, I don't think current IDEs do this any more.

Comment: Valid point, although I don't think there were many IDEs when this feature was implemented (or left accidentally) :-)

Comment: I think is in the category of `static transient` fields. ;)

Comment: And public constructors on an abstract class.

Comment: IntelliJ does this. My version is IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.3 Build #IU-145.1617.

Comment: @Dormouse, it's interesting, because Android Studio (3.1.4 Build #AI-173.4907809) does not :(

Comment: NetBeans doesn't.

Answer (score 19):

Final annotations of method parameters are always only relevant to the method implementation never to the caller. Therefore, there is no real reason to use them in interface method signatures. Unless you want to follow the same consistent coding standard, which requires final method parameters, in all method signatures. Then it is nice to be able to do so.

Answer (score 6):

**Update:** Original answer below was written without fully understanding the question, and therefore does not directly address the question `:)` Nevertheless, it must be informative for those looking to understand the general use of `final` keyword.

As for the question, I would like to quote my own comment from below.

> I believe you're not forced to implement the finality of an argument to leave you free to decide whether it should be *final* or not in your own implementation.
>
> But yes, it sounds rather odd that you can declare it `final` in the interface, but have it *non-final* in the implementation. It would have made more sense if either:
>
> **a.** `final` keyword was not allowed for interface (abstract) method arguments (but you can use it in implementation), or
> **b.** declaring an argument as `final` in interface would force it to be declared `final` in implementation (but not forced for non-finals).

---

I can think of two reasons why a method signature can have `final` parameters: **Beans** and **Objects** (*Actually, they are both the same reason, but slightly different contexts.*)

**Objects:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder cookingPot = new StringBuilder("Water ");
    addVegetables(cookingPot);
    addChicken(cookingPot);
    System.out.println(cookingPot.toString());
    // ^--- OUTPUT IS: Water Carrot Broccoli Chicken ChickenBroth 
    //      We forgot to add cauliflower. It went into the wrong pot.
}

private static void addVegetables(StringBuilder cookingPot) {
    cookingPot.append("Carrot ");
    cookingPot.append("Broccoli ");
    cookingPot = new StringBuilder(cookingPot.toString());
    //   ^--- Assignment allowed...
    cookingPot.append("Cauliflower ");
}

private static void addChicken(final StringBuilder cookingPot) {
    cookingPot.append("Chicken ");
    //cookingPot = new StringBuilder(cookingPot.toString());
    //     ^---- COMPILATION ERROR! It is final.
    cookingPot.append("ChickenBroth ");
}
```

The `final` keyword ensured that we will not accidentally create a new *local* cooking pot by showing a compilation error when we attempted to do so. This ensured the chicken broth is added to our original cooking pot which the `addChicken` method got. Compare this to `addVegetables` where we lost the cauliflower because it added that to a new *local* cooking pot instead of the original pot it got.

**Beans:**
It is the same concept as objects *(as shown above)*. Beans are essentially `Object`s in Java. However, beans (JavaBeans) are used in various applications as a convenient way to store and pass around a defined collection of related data. Just as the `addVegetables` could mess up the cooking process by creating a new cooking pot `StringBuilder` and throwing it away with the cauliflower, it could also do the same with a cooking pot *JavaBean*.

Comment: Ok. It's not really a correct answer to the question, (since I'm not forced to make my implementation of the interface method take final arguments, even if the interface says so), but it's still helpful, in that it's a nice explanation of why making method parameters final is a good idea to begin with.

Comment: I believe you're not forced to implement the finality of an argument to leave you free to decide whether it should be *final* or not in your own implementation. But yes, it sounds rather odd that you can declare it `final` in the interface, but have it *non-final* in the implementation. It would have made more sense if either **(a)** `final` keyword was not allowed for interface (abstract) method arguments (but you can use it in implementation), or **(b)** declaring an argument as `final` in interface would force it to be declared `final` in implementation (but not forced for non-finals).

Comment: _"It's not really a correct answer to the question"_ You're right, I don't know what I was thinking... must have been the early wee hours of July or something. `:)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe it may be a superfluous detail, as whether it's final or not is an implementation detail.

(Sort of like declaring methods/members in an interface as public.)