# What difference does it make to declare a Java interface method signature as final and non-final

Tags: java, interface, final

what difference does it make in a Java Interface to declare the method signature as final and non-final?

```
int setName(String name);

int setName(final String name);
```

Comment: @Keoki while this is true, it kinda defeats the purpose of Stack Overflow.

Comment: You could rephrase your question as you are using a final parameter.

Comment: Related: [Final arguments in interface methods - what's the point?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5380177/final-arguments-in-interface-methods-whats-the-point)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Section 8.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.4.1) of the Java Language specification allows the parameters in any method declaration (and that includes the ones in interfaces) to be declared final. However, since this does not influence the method's [signature](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#38649), declaring a parameter of an abstract function as `final` has no effect. Since all methods in an interface are [implicitely abstract](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.1.4), both variants are equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The most complete answer I could find on google is [this one](http://www.coderanch.com/t/378411/java/java/final-method-argument).

It's nice they mention the link with using anonymous inner classes as it's a strong use case for final parameters.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 1):

A couple of incidental differences

- It can be used by the IDE as a hint.  e.g. when you get the IDE to auto-generate your implemented methods, it will make the parameters `final` by default in the same way it will re-use the same parameter names even though these are not part of the signature either.
- the modifier `final` is available via reflection and could be used by a framework for some implied purpose.

Comment: Wondering if `final` could cause problems with, for example, OSGI?

Comment: @vikingsteve If you use Karaf+iPOJO, it will set final fields. (And change them as required)