# Trying to figure out how to pass a parameter to a thread using the Runnable thread class

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to create my first server, a simple chat server.

I have a `Runnable` class called `cCleanThread`  that creates a thread that uses sleep to call 
 c`Globals.mUserList.Clean();` every 10 seconds.

I would like to have it so each instance of `cCleanThread`  would have its own `mUserList` object.  I can't figure out a easy way to do this.

I figured I would somw how have to pass in a parameter for a `mUserList` when I create my `cCleanThread` object?

code

```
public class cCleanThread   implements Runnable {

Thread runner;
public cCleanThread() {
}

public cCleanThread(String threadName) {
    runner = new Thread(this, threadName); // (1) Create a new thread.
    System.out.println(runner.getName());
    runner.start(); // (2) Start the thread.
}

public void run() {
    //Display info about this particular thread
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
     while(true)
     {

         try {
            Thread.sleep(20*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
         cGlobals.mUserList.Clean(); 
     }
}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can I pass a variable into a new Runnable declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297261/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-into-a-new-runnable-declaration)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the `mUserList` to the thread constructor:

```
public class cCleanThread implements Runnable {

    private final UserList localUserList;

    public cCleanThread(String threadName, UserList mUserList) {
        this.localUserList = mUserList;
        //...
    }

    public void run() {
        //...
        localUserList.Clean(); 
    }
}
```

The simply create thread with different arguments:

```
Thread first  = new cCleanThread("Thread-Foo", fooUsers);
Thread second = new cCleanThread("Thread-Bar", barUsers);
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you, I'm sort of learning java as I work on this project.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer. It is more like an improvement.

If you want to run clean every 10 second, you can use [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) class. This is the [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/UsejavautilTimertoscheduleatasktoexecuteonce5secondshavepassed.htm). The thread is done automatically for you.

Comment: The Timer is in the Swing-package. Are you sure about its dependencies?

Comment: Sorry, I have changed the link to java.util.Timer.

Answer (score 1):

Add `mUserList` as instance variable in `cCleanThread` class and initialize it in the constructor. Since every thread corresponds to an instance of `cCleanThread` instance, there will be exactly one `mUserList` for each thread. This `mUserList` instance will be accessible to your `run()` method since they'll both be in the same class.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the SceduledExecutorService: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable, long, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)

And take a further look at the new Threadsafe-Collections:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html